# Cross reference and circular dependency. Header including itself indirectly

Tags: c++, inheritance, header, circular-dependency, cross-reference

placeable.h

```
#include "selectable.h"

class placeable : selectable
{
..
};
```

selectable.h

```
#include "game.h"


class selectable
{
..
};
```

game.h

```
#include "placeable.h"

class game
{
...
class placeable* holding;
...
};
```

Basically placeable.h includes selectable.h which includes game.h which includes placeable.h again.

The only solution i can think of is placing the placeable* in a new header, making it static/global and then include this new header in game.h and selectable.h.

I'm sorry i dint include header guards in the upper code. I assumed it was obvious.
Header guards does not help in this case because of the inheritance, same thing goes with forward declaring.

Answer (score 5):

Only include headers if you **MUST**

Use forward declaration in preference to including:

You only need to include the header for class `X` iff:

- You have a member of the class 'X'
- You derive from the class 'X'
- You pass a parameter of class 'X' by value.

Otherwise a forward declaration will suffice.

```
//  -> Don't do this #include "placeable.h"
class     placeable;  // forward declare
                      // Fine if you are using a pointer.

class game
{
    ...
    class placeable* holding;
    ...
};
```

PS. Add header guards.

Answer (score 3):

This means you have not properly encapsulated the functionality of your design.  It should be higher-level includes lower level, not same-level includes same-level.  If game is the higher level then selectable should not include game.h.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solved problem. It's called header guards. Try this inside ALL of your header files:

```
#ifndef __NAMEOFTHEFILE_H__
#define __NAMEOFTHEFILE_H__
// nothing goes above the ifndef above

// everything in the file goes here

// nothing comes after the endif below
#endif
```

Also, you can do this (this is known as a forward reference):

```
// game.h

class placeable;

class game { ...
    placeable* p;
};
```

Comment: Header guards only prevent multiple inclusion, they don't protect you from circular designs.

Comment: And did the info about forward references help? You need header guards. And you need forward references.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. Circular headers dependency. Solution - #ifndef ...
2. Allocating space for unknown type. Solution - class placeable;

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

Use header guards in each of your header files to avoid this problem. In general, your header files should like this:

```
#ifndef PLACEABLE_H
#define PLACEABLE_H

//
// Class definitions and function declarations
//

#endif
```